# send xml data to server and get response

Tags: iphone, xml

i am making an app in which user's data is send to a server...the data should be in xml format.

presently i have made a string and put all into it...like following format
NSString *s=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@",name.text,address.text];
(this is just an example i have made a string with full xml tags including xml version tag)
and then send this through http post method....
i did it but dont know how to get response of server...please help ...any code will be helpful.....
waiting for answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLConnection). You essentially create a connection, register a delegate, kick off the request and build the response as the data is passed to your delegate.

I'm working from memory here, but essentially:

- Create an NSURLRequest for your request to your server
- Create an NSURLConnection using the initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate init method, passing a suitable delegate.

The request will be made, and the response will be passed back to your delegate in:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

I've not tested this, but something like:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SERVER"] 

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setHTTPBody:@"Your XML"];

NSURLConnection * conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Then in your delegate you can build the response using the data provided in the didReceiveData:(NSData *)data and didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response methods.

Comment: very useful thanks for this exact and correct answer....i have not tried it but looking for this type thanks again.....voted and accepted...

Comment: just want to ask that should i send string that contained xml data or an attached file that has the same data ?

Comment: Just the string, so [request setHTTPBody:@"<xml><content>fhhf</content></xml>"]; should be fine.